# Mouse Click in Mac OS & Detect Which OS Application is Running in

Tags: c#, macos, mono, monomac

I want to use Mono to allow my C# program (currently WPF but will change it to Windows Forms or Silverlight so that Mono will work) that currently works in Windows to work on a Mac.

I use native windows code to detect when a mouse is clicked, and also to click the mouse, like so:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);
```

In order for this to work on a Mac I need to first be able to detect whether the program is running on a Mac or in Windows, and then run the appropriate code for detecting whether a mouse is clicked, or for clicking the mouse. Something like:

```
if (runningInWindows())
{
    // Windows mouse click...
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(X, Y);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    // Or if I want to detect a mouse click...
    bool mouseClicked = GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.LButton) != 0;
}
else
{
    // Running on a Mac, so do Mac mouse click...
    // Or detect a mouse click on a Mac...
}
```

Essentially I have 3 questions:

1. How do you click the mouse on a Mac? (equivalent of mouse_event)
2. How do you detect a mouse click on a Mac? (equivalent of GetAsyncKeyState)
3. How do you detect which Operating System your application is running in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detecting the operating system is easy, you can find some platform detection code [here](http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2010/01/25/integrating_gtk_application_mac).

The other two are harder. You'd have to look at Apple's native Carbon or Cocoa APIs and figure out how to do the things you want, then P/Invoke those APIs. FWIW, I don't know whether it's actually possible to control the mouse with public API. There do seem to be some sites around that explain how to do [some of this stuff](http://allancraig.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=137%3agetting-mouse-coordinates&catid=39%3aobjective-c&Itemid=86).

For a start, getting the mouse position seems to be possible via `HIGetMousePosition` (Carbon) or `[NSEvent mouseLocation]` (Cocoa). Although a lot of high-level Carbon APIs are deprecated, it still forms the core of the low-level C API used by Cocoa. It could be tricky figuring out how to read Carbon events and extract information from them, OTOH Cocoa means interop with Objective-C, which is more complicated than P/Invoke - but MonoMac has some APIs that can make that easier.